# Meaning of DBSCAN MinPts Parameter in ELKI

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki

I have a seemingly trivial question. I need someone to clarify for me the meaning of the DBSCAN *MinPts* parameter in the ELKI implementation.

If I use a value of *k* = 4 to plot a sorted *k*-dist graph, it means the distance of a point *p* to its 4th nearest neighbor. This means that the neighborhood contains 5 points (*k* + 1); the 4 neighbors plus point *p*.

In ELKI, does *MinPts* mean the neighbors only or does it also include the point *p*? In the above case, should it be set to 4 or 5?

The [original DBSCAN paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf) (Ester et al. 1996) talks of setting *MinPts* to k (*MinPts* = 4). The [DBSCAN Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) also seems to imply that *MinPts* refers to the neighbors around *p*. However, ELKI seems to expect that *MinPts* is set to *k* + 1 (*MinPts* = 5).

Someone kindly clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Arguments *pro* including the query point:

If you are in a database context, and you send a query to the database

> Select all objects within a radius of r around coordinates x,y,z

then the **database *would* include the query point**, *if* it is stored in the database. In particular, you could easily remove it, if it was not desired to be included. **From a database point of view, queries *should* include the query point**, if it is in the database, and not, if it is not stored in the database.

Even more, if you do density estimation, then *every* data point should contribute to the density, shouldn't it? Why would one point be special? What about other points with the exact same coordinates? What if you estimate density at a point that is *not* in the database? You would see an abrupt density increase if you move a tiny bit away from your query point!

If you try to define the k-nearest-neighbors as a query to a database D, and do *not* require the query point x to be part of the database, then it follows naturally that the result should include the query point *if* it is part of D.

### Arguments *contra* including the query point:

On the other hand, it is counterintuitive that the 1-nearest-neighbor usually is the query point. Usually, when you are looking for "the nearest neighbor", you *do* mean "the nearest *other* object", unfortunately.
Even if this would formally translate to "nearest object to the coordinates of my query point in my database *without* my query point".

### Inconsistently used in literature:

Unfortunately, this is not used consistently in literature.
Some articles/authors/applications do—and some do not—include the query point. I can name plenty of examples from literature for *both* cases.

Even a single article sometimes includes the query point in one figure, but not in the other!

There will *never* be a solution that behaves according to the expectations of everybody, because people do have different ideas of what is "correct", unfortunately.

### Be specific, and double-check!

You will have to decide on what *you* want the behaviour to be, and double check everything if it behaves the way you expect it to be. *Document* your decisions and observations.

Please check yourself if the implementation of the k-distance graph in ELKI includes the query point. We may even (have) changed the behavior of this class for version 0.7 or 0.8; so it may be different for me than it is for you. **Really, really look at the source of the *exact* version that you are using.**

If the k-distance graph does *not* include the query point, you would need to use the 3-distance for `minPts=4`. If it *does include* the query point, then 4-distance agrees with `minPts=4`. I'm pretty sure that DBSCAN *does* count the query point for above reasons (database point of view, density estimation point of view). Thus for DBSCAN, minPts=1 is nonsense (every point is a core point), and minPts=2 is single-linkage clustering (any epsilon-neighbors are merged). Only at minPts > 2 you start getting real DBSCAN results.

GDBSCAN suggests to use `2*dim-1` instead of 4; I usually start with `minPts=10`, then try `20`. There are several reasons to choose a larger `minPts`:

- Higher dimensionality usually requires larger `minPts` (but for textual data, dimensionality is meaningless - at most choose by the intrinsic dimensionality)
- Noise: the noisier your data, the higher you need to go with `minPts`
- Duplicates: if you have lots of duplicates, you again need to increase `minPts`

But don't overshoot. Index efficiency drops substantially with a large query radiuses. You want to choose `minPts` as small as you can, while still getting an interesting result. Also **do use multiple values**, to get different views.

Remember that clustering is **explorative** data mining. It is meant to require you to experiment with parameters, and study the result, repeat. Because **there is no *correct* clustering result**. The quality of a clustering result is whether you can get a *new insight* on your data. A clustering that only reproduces a known result has in fact failed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am using ELKI version 0.6.5~20141030. As you advise, I have looked at the source of the `KNNDistancesSampler.java` file that I'm using to compute the KNN distances and it shows that `k` is `minPts` - 1. It does _not_ include the query point. My intention was therefore to use `k` = 4 and `minPts` = 5 but I will experiment with other values as you suggest.